# How to optimize insert actions in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that needs to log each users access, that is, each access I create a record in the database. This writing action in the database is a problem today, because the insert query, although simple, takes time. Is there any technique to optimize this? I thought about saving in memory and when I get to a certain number save everything in the database at once. Anyone have any tips on how to optimize this?

The page has an average of 100,000 hits per day. The query I make is something like:

```
INSERT INTO `visit` (`page_id`) VALUES ('16163')
```

This query takes about 0.1195 and has been a problem since it runs at each access.

I've optimized everything I could, I just do not know what to do with it.

Comment: I don't think this is a question about coding. But this will depend on a lot of things. The sensitivity of the data, whether you can risk losing parts of it, the number of users etc....

Comment: Place the insert into a separate thread so it doesn't hinder the performance overall. You provided very little details with regards to the issue. There are numerous factors to consider.